# how do i put a draggable back in it's droppable using only code

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

The basic concept of my app is to map a group of pallets onto a truck. I have a page that allows the user to drag a draggable div "pallet" and place it in a droppable div "slot" on the truck. The weights for each row, left and right columns and the truck total weight are calculated on the fly. I then pass all of the information to a page to print a table of pallets and slots so an operator can then load the truck. The problem is restoring the load if the user only loads half the truck and then wants to come back at a latter time to finish. I know how to save any number of data points, but i cannot find a way to put the "pallets" back in their "slots" when i rebuild the page.

Here are the div's for the pallets, some of the slots and the drop procedure (i'm not sure what else is needed)

```
      //load the playpen with the pallets that belong on this truck
  for (var i = 0; i < noPallets; i++) {
      $('<div id="' + PalletIDs[i] + '">' + PalletIDs[i] + '<br>' + Storage[i] + ':' + Weights[i] + '</div>').data('pallet', 
      { ID: PalletIDs[i], Weight: Weights[i], columnNo: 0, rowNo: 0, tierNo:0 }).appendTo('#playpen').draggable({
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#playpen div',
      cursor: 'move',
      start: handlePalletStart,
      revert: true
  });
  }
  // Create the pallet slots for truck left
   var words = ['C<br>one', 'C<br>two', 'C<br>three', 'C<br>four', 'C<br>five', 'C<br>six', 'C<br>seven', 'C<br>eight', 'C<br>nine', 'C<br>ten', 'C<br>eleven'];
   for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
     position = 1000 + (i * 10) + 3
       $('<div id="' + position + '">' + words[i - 1] + '</div>').data('position', { columnNo: 1, rowNo: i, tierNo: 3 }).appendTo('#truckleftC').droppable({
           accept: '#playpen div',
           hoverClass: 'hovered',
           drop: handlePalletDrop
       });
   }

    function handlePalletDrop(event, ui) {
    // this is the truck location we are about to drop into

  var columnNo = $(this).data('position').columnNo;
  var rowNo = $(this).data('position').rowNo;
  var tierNo = $(this).data('position').tierNo;
  // this is pallet information
  var palletID = ui.draggable.data('pallet').ID;
  var weight = ui.draggable.data('pallet').Weight;
  // if the pallet was already in a positio, we need to zero that position
  if (ui.draggable.data('pallet').columnNo != 0) {
      oldposition = ui.draggable.data('pallet').columnNo * 1000 + ui.draggable.data('pallet').rowNo * 10 + ui.draggable.data('pallet').tierNo;
      //          alert(oldposition);
    for (var h = 0; h <= 65; h++) {
        if (aryTWeight[h][0] == oldposition) {
            aryTWeight[h][1] = 0;
        }
    }
  }

  // set the position in the truck for this pallet
  ui.draggable.data('pallet').columnNo = columnNo;
  ui.draggable.data('pallet').rowNo = rowNo;
  ui.draggable.data('pallet').tierNo = tierNo;
  // set the weight for this position in the truck
  position = columnNo * 1000 + rowNo * 10 + tierNo
 //      alert(position);
  for (var h = 0; h <= 65; h++) {
      if (aryTWeight[h][0] == position) {
          aryTWeight[h][1] = weight;
     }
  }
 //     alert(columnNo + ' : ' + rowNo + ' : ' + tierNo);

  // set the hidden text box with the palletid so data can be posted to next page
  for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
      element = document.forms[0].elements[i];
      if (element.name == oldposition) {
          element.value = 0;
      };
      if (element.name == position) {
          element.value = palletID;
      };
  }
  // set all of the weights for rows, columns and totals
  calcWeights();

  ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
  ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' });
  ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
```

}

Comment: It might be worth updating your post to include some of your code. It's a little vague at the moment.

Comment: i added some of the code. i'm not sure what other parts may be needed

Answer (score 1):

You could store x and y coordinates of the loaded pallets and then when you're rebuilding the page set the palettes' css position: absolute; and set top and left to the x and y stored. And append them to the droppable div programmatically.

It all depends on how your slots work, if you have lots of droppables and each droppable can only contain one draggable then just store the pairs and append the draggable to droppable with jquery when you're rebuilding the page.

```
var html = '<div id="myDraggableDiv"></div>'

$('#' + droppableId).append(html);
```

If you need any special css like exact top and left add it in style attribute or with jquery after the element is created.

Comment: this did not work. it turned the pallet (draggable) into a slot (droppable) and would not let me move it.

Comment: did you try to initialise the draggable after appending it? with  $( "#myDraggableDiv" ).draggable();

Comment: ok. i initialize the draggable, but it still looks like a slot (droppable) instead of a pallet (draggable), the start event does not fire and it does not drop into a new slot (droppable) when i drag/drop it. i am assuming that my pallet (draggable) thinks its a slot (droppable) since i appended it to a slot (droppable)

Comment: Martina, thank for your help! I found something that worked and all i had to do was move my drop code to it's own function so i could call it on a drop or on a position.

Comment: var mylocation = $('#1013');
        var mypallet = $('#200002');
        $(mypallet).position({
              my: "center",
              at: "center",
              of: mylocation
          });
          mydrop(mypallet, mylocation);

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out.